# Angular custom validator is not throwing an error when using subscribe in it

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

I am trying to create custom validator which needs to hit two endpoint to fetch needed data and then compare properties of the data and if they are not equal then I want to throw an error. Here is the validator.

```
 checkIfSalaIsFull(control: AbstractControl): {[salaIsFull: string] : boolean}{
    if(control.value !=null){
      this.salaService.findActiveCards(control.value).subscribe(karty=>{
        this.salaService.findSalaByNRSali(control.value).subscribe(sala =>{
          if(karty.length === sala.pojemnosc){
            console.log(karty.length);
            console.log(sala.pojemnosc);
            return {'salaIsFull' : true};
          }
        });
      });
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The problem is that error is not thrown even though console.log show the same value for showed properties.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nr_sali">Numer sali</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="nr_sali" formControlName="nr_sali">
      <option *ngFor="let sala of sale" [value]="sala.nr_sali" >{{sala.nr_sali}} - {{sala.oddzial}}</option>

    </select>

    <span *ngIf="formAddKarta.get('nr_sali').errors?.salaIsFull"
          class="help-block text-danger">
          Sala jest pełna
    </span>
</div>
```

My backend is working, I checked it with postman.

Here is also a setup of FormGroup which I am using:

```
 this.formAddKarta = new FormGroup({
      data_przyjecia: new FormControl(null, [KartyListaComponent.checkIfDateIsLessThanToday.bind(this),
        Validators.required]),
      godzina_przyjecia: new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]),
      data_wypisu: new FormControl(null),
      nr_sali: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,this.checkIfSalaIsFull.bind(this)]),
      pesel: new FormControl(this.pesel)
    });
```

I set this custom validator in Validators table in nr_sali FormControl.

**EDIT:**

I tried to use map instead of subscribe but then it is not sending request to retrieve sala, only sending request to retreive karty.

```
 checkIfSalaIsFull(control: AbstractControl): {[salaIsFull: string] : boolean}{
    if(control.value !=null){
      this.salaService.findActiveCards(control.value).subscribe(karty=>{
        this.salaService.findSalaByNRSali(control.value).pipe(map(sala =>{
          if(karty.length === sala.pojemnosc){
            console.log(karty.length);
            console.log(sala.pojemnosc);
            return {'salaIsFull' : true};
          }else{
            return null;
          }
        }));
      });
    }else{
      return null;
    }

  }
```

Comment: You need to use map instead of subscribe and return the mapped observable. Also you need to set it as an async validator

Comment: I am new to angular could you show the example of how to do this? I have no idea how to use map to be honest. @AluanHaddad

Comment: You can find information about Map here: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators

Basically you want to use `.map(sala=>` rather than `subscribe(sala=>`

Comment: @Rinktacular, When I use .map(sala=> I receive error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Sala>"

Comment: Make sure to use this at the top of your file:

 `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: @Rinktacular even after adding this line I am getting same error :(

Comment: The reason it still doesn't work after your edit is that you are still using subscribe. You can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need to use async validator instead of validator, because you need to send request, and you need to put your function as third parameter in your formControl (as Async validator)
2. your validator function should be return `Observable<ValidationErrors | null> | Promise<ValidationErrors | null>`
3. you need to use `switchMap and map` instead of subscription

here is the code example

**imports**

```
import { map, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/observable";
```

**async validator example**

```
  checkIfSalaIsFull(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    if (control.value != null) {
      return this.salaService.findActiveCards(control.value).pipe(
        switchMap(karty => {
          return this.salaService.findSalaByNRSali(control.value).pipe(
            map(sala => {
                console.log(karty.length);
                console.log(sala.pojemnosc);
                return karty.length === sala.pojemnosc ? { salaIsFull: true } : null;

            })
          );
        })
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

**Form Implementation example**

```
 this.formAddKarta = new FormGroup({
      data_przyjecia: new FormControl(null, [
KartyListaComponent.checkIfDateIsLessThanToday.bind(this),  /** <-- if this function send the request you need to change this one too */

        Validators.required]),
      godzina_przyjecia: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required] ),
      data_wypisu: new FormControl(null),
      nr_sali: new FormControl(null, 
[Validators.required],
 [this.checkIfSalaIsFull.bind(this)]),  /** <-- third argument of formControl is the async validators array */
      pesel: new FormControl(this.pesel)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my above comments, you want to use map instead of subscribe.  Since Angular 6, rxjs (the library map comes from) wraps requires it's operations to be wrapped in a pipe function like so:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operations'

...

this.salaService.findSalaByNRSali(control.value).pipe(map(sala => { 
  // Do work
  // ...
}));
```

Comment: So when I added map I can see in the logs that Angular is not sending Request to receive sala. Only sending request to receive karty. I want to send both requests. @Rinktacular

Comment: Please take a look at EDIT